# Is inertia present at the level of elementary particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, elementary-particles, inertia

Is a more massive elementary particle will experience more [inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia) in a one-on-one particle interaction?

Answer (score 2):

Inertia is a property possessed by anything with mass. Subatomic particles have it, just like baseballs and planets.

Answer (score 1):

Inertia is a concept that is inherent in the two first laws of Newton, but not a quantity one can measure with units used in physical measurements.

> [Inertia is a quality](https://www.thoughtco.com/inertia-2698982) of all objects made of matter that possess mass. They keep doing what they are doing until a force changes their speed or direction.

In [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inertia)

> Inertia is the resistance of any physical object to a change in its velocity. This includes changes to the object's speed or direction of motion.

The [two first laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion) of mechanics are:

> Law 1. A body remains at rest, or in motion at a constant speed in a straight line, unless acted upon by a force.

> Law 2. When a body is acted upon by a force, the time rate of change of its momentum equals the force.

[Mathematically the second law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_laws_of_motion#Second_law) that defines force can be written as  :

$\vec{F}=d\vec{p}/dt$ where $\vec{p}$ is the momentum vector.

At the level of quantum mechanics and particle physics this allows us to answer that yes, particles have inertia as interactions of a particles transfer $d\vec{p}/dt$.